# How do you make the camera point in the same direction throughout a animation?

Tags: camera, path

I am trying to make a animation looking at a building facade. As the camera moves along the path it rotates or points the wrong way. 
How do I lock the view of the camera so that it continues to point in one direction and not rotate?
Sorry if this has been asked before
Cheers

Comment: Is the path just a circle?

Comment: no, the path is supposed to go parallel to the building looking at the ground floor and then the first

Answer (score 1):

Use [Track To] Constraint or perhaps secondly the [Locked Track] Constraint on the Camera.
You can use this constraint as a complement to the camera  moving along a path.
Often you may use a third object to as a target to look at specific locations of another object.  In the building example you could move any non rendered object to focus the track on floors or windows.

[image]

[image]
These constraints will point the camera at a target which can be moving or stationary.

There are free video tutorials on the settings of these constraints on various websites.  You can also experiment to determine the correct settings for you in a few minutes.

Comment: Cheers atomicbezierslinger, I gave that a shot and was copying some youtube videos but the camera was still rotating. I tried to get it track an object that was some distance behind the building but that didn't work either.
In the end I have gone for Transform constraint and Limit Rotation. This seems to have locked it in the desired position. 
Cheers for the hep and quick response

Comment: It works with the correct settings, without question.  Also check the rotation of the camera itself. Sometimes I clear the rotation of the camera.  Sometimes I rotate on a given axis by 90 degrees.  Please show your settings in the original question. Please know I intermittently look at BSE, then my time expires and I am off the computer.  BSE time is unpredictable for me.